# What is seasonal-irregular (SI) ratios and its use in seasonal adjustment?

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I am involved in some seasonal adjustment (SA) work, and the SI ratios is always computed when I run the X12 ARIMA programs. Hence I would like to understand this statistics better, but I can't find a lot of useful information when I googled.

What is seasonal-irregular (SI) component vs SI ratios?

What is the use of the SI ratios in seasonal adjustment (SA) test statistics?

Thank you

Comment: X12Arima is a filter based method of seasonal adjustment. In the process e series undergoes a number of moving average type operations to obtain the 'trend-cycle' component which when subtracted from main series leaves SI component. On component vs ratio, google multiplicative vs additive seasonal adjustment or unidentified components modelling in time series. I do not the the answer of your last question (if I understand it correctly) about use of SI ratios in seasonality tests.

Comment: Also for extensive details see [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.census.gov/ts/x12a/v03/x12adocV03.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjjr6PjnZjwAhViH7cAHYkaCvAQFjAAegQIBhAC&usg=AOvVaw2TK5IQnvt8321Q2Xmgm5RN&cshid=1619313805472).

Comment: @Dayne, many thanks for your reply!. Could u also help with my other query - [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/521213/what-is-the-importance-of-moving-seasonality-in-seasonal-adjustment]?